# Join salesforce objects with AMPscript within the same email

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, cross-object, outer-join

I want to create a transactional email for orders, containing data about the consumer (Account object), data about his order (Order object) and data about the ordered products (products object). The order email will be sent using a triggered email.

How can i use AMPscript to join the 3 tables in the same email? I can't use the lookup function because I'm not working with data extensions.

I used the following code and I got data from two objects but I have no idea how because the mapping seems wrong:

```
%%[
    set @res1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("OBJECT1","Id,Field11,Field12","Field12", "=", Field12)
    set @res1Row = ROW(@res1,1)
    set @Id = FIELD(@res1Row,"Id")
    set @Field11= FIELD(@res1Row,"Field11")
    set @Field12= FIELD(@res1Row,"Field12")
    set @res2 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("OBJECT2","Field21,Field22","Field22", "=", @Id)
    set @res2Row = Row(@res2,1)
    set @Field21= FIELD(@res2Row,"Field21")
    set @Field22= FIELD(@res2Row,"Field22")
]%%

%%=v(@Field11)=%%...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge you are facing is that account <-> contact is a one to many relationship, and account <-> order and contact <-> order are many to many as well.

Therefore, what you need to do is something like this below (i'm assuming you have the IDs available to you as part of the triggered events data);

```
%%[

VAR @ContactId, @AccountId, @OrderId
SET @ContactId = ContactId
SET @AccountId = AccountId
SET @OrderId = OrderID

/* modify code below to the various objects */

set @res1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("OBJECT1","Id,Field11,Field12","Field12", "=", Field12)
set @res1Row = ROW(@res1,1)
set @Id = FIELD(@res1Row,"Id")
set @Field11= FIELD(@res1Row,"Field11")
set @Field12= FIELD(@res1Row,"Field12")

set @res2 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("OBJECT2","Field21,Field22","Field22", "=", @Id)
set @res2Row = Row(@res2,1)
set @Field21= FIELD(@res2Row,"Field21")
set @Field22= FIELD(@res2Row,"Field22")

]%%
```